# (A)sexual reproduction of plants

Tags: botany, reproduction

Are all plants capable of sexual reproduction? Some can do asexual reproduction as well but I haven't found any plants that aren't capable of sexual reproduction. Is it correct to say all plants are capable of sexual reproduction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not. There are common plants that can only reproduce asexually.

It's likely you can buy produce from several plants which are unable to do so at your local supermarket. The most famous example is, of course, the banana which is a sterile mutant and all bananas of a particular variety are clones, but some seedless varieties of grapes and oranges would also count (although most seedless fruit you find in the supermarket are actually produced with hormonal treatments rather than being asexual varieties).

These plants are examples of artificial selection but there are also examples of plants that have lost the ability to sexually reproduce in the wild. The evening primrose is a good example, with some 30% of species in the genus *Oenothera* having evolved to be asexual ([Hollister et al, 2015](http://mbe.oxfordjournals.org/content/32/4/896.full)), but this is not the [only example](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-1345-0_15). It is likely that, just as in animal species, asexuality has short (on an evolutionary timescale) term advantages but results in lower fitness in the longer term.

Comment: How come bananas lost their ability to reproduce sexually?

Comment: Because bananas with seeds are nowhere near as edible, humans have selected the varieties without for cultivation.

Comment: Did some plants also lose their ability to reproduce sexually due to natural (non-human) circumstances?

Comment: @Koekje: Yes, see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks 1000 times for answering my questions! (I've been looking on the internet for at least 2 hours without finding any evidence for plants that solely reproduce sexually)

Comment: So it turns out that what I said about seedless fruit in the supermarket is largely incorrect, while some are produced from seedless varieties most are produced with hormonal treatments that induce normal seeded plants to produce seedless fruit and these plants can reproduce normally when allowed to do so. Bananas are an exception to this, and really are obligately asexual.

Comment: Does "heterosis" fit into your context? From Hollister who you link to I got, e.g. Dorken, M.E. and Eckert, C.G. (2001) Severely reduced sexual reproduction in northern populations of a clonal plant, Decodon verticillatus (Lythraceae). Maybe "banana" is just an example for all sorts of plant losing their capability when: inbreeding. "Obligately" could even, conversely mean: all other forms extinguished.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I think you might be referring to ***apomictic*** plants.

Apomictic plants are those plants that are unable to complete [the normal process of sexual reproduction](http://www.kullabs.com/classes/subjects/units/lessons/notes/note-detail/8527) and have to *use another alternative pathway to produce an embryo*. One way out is through **asexual** reproduction, and another is called ***Agamospermy***.

**Agamospermy** is basically the process of formation of seeds ***without sexual reproduction.*** Agamospermy is further of two types, *sporophytic* agamospermy and *gametophytic* agamospermy.

In ***sporophytic agamospermy***, the embryo is directly formed by diploid sporophytic cells such as those of the nucellus of the ovule, and this is also known as adventive embryogeny. More often than not, in adventive embryogeny, multiple embryos are formed(this is called adventive polyembryony, but i will not go into that for now).

However in the case of ***Gametophytic Agamospermy***, the nucellus cells first develop into a diploid egg cell( the egg cell is normally haploid, however, in this case meiosis is not possible so egg cell has to be diploid). This diploid egg cell now undergoes parthenogenesis(i.e, formation of embryo without fertilisation or syngamy) to produce an embryo which is a clone of the parent.

Now coming to the examples. Apomixis is really well marked in ***[Citrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citrus) plants*** like oranges, lemons, etc and also in ***Mango***.[image]
Also, some varieties of ***apple*** are known to show parthenogenesis(**DO NOT** confuse with [parthenocarpy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenocarpy)!!)

[image]

Even ***Rubus*** shows the same.

[image]

Comment: Refering to question, are those plants not capable at all of sexual reproduction; have they completely opted out of or lost their sexual way of reproduction?
I think your definition of "sexual reproduction" is based on gametes as special cells being a prerequisite. Some authors may consider Apomixis sexual reproduction as the term implies crossing over of genes. I think the  question: "Can parthenogenesis be considered sexual reproduction?" pretty much relates to your answer.